# How to display all items of alert builder dialog with scroll veiw?

Tags: android

when more than one edit text. for example we try to populate 30 edittext.So how to display all edittext in one window?

Comment: use scroll view and put those EditText's under it.

Comment: how to use scroll view in all edittext?

Comment: @momrfaruq, check my answer below, and let me know whether it is working or not.

Comment: I want to dynamically add alert builder with many edittext from activity.

Answer (score 0):

Okay for adding edit-text runtime you can try below code.

```
LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
main = new LinearLayout(this);
main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout editTextLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    editTextLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    main.addView(editTextLayout);

    EditText editText1 = new EditText(this);
    editText1.setId(id1);
    editTextLayout.addView(editText1);

    editTexts.add(editText1);

    EditText editText2 = new EditText(this);
    editText2.setId(id2);
    editTextLayout.addView(editText2);

    editTexts.add(editText2);

    EditText editText3 = new EditText(this);
    editText3.setId(id3);
    editTextLayout.addView(editText3);

    editTexts.add(editText3);

   ...
   ....
  .....

    EditText editText30 = new EditText(this);
    editText3.setId(id30);
    editTextLayout.addView(editText30);

    editTexts.add(editText30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText14"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText15"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        ------
        ------
        ------ 
        so on...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```